# Looking for an image rotator with a numbered tab

Tags: image, slideshow

Not sure this is the sort of question I should be asking here but here goes...

I'm looking to find a flash or javascript applet that can display say 5 images and at the bottom of the images there is a tab with a number on that you can use to jump to that image.

I can't think of a way of searching for this particular thing, and I can't even find an example! The nearest I can say is that it might be on a news site with different images for different stories and you would click on the image for the story that interests you or select the numbered tab at the bottom.

Does anyone know what I'm looking for or where I can find this in action so I can use it as an example? Could be Flash or javascript i think...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want something like this http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider1.7/02.html

This above plugin ( [Easy Slider 1.7 - Numeric Navigation jQuery Slider](http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider) ) supports this out of the box..